Prove that if $f=\frac{1}{(x-a_1)*(x-a_2)...}$, then $f=\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{k_2}{x-a_2}+...$ where $k_1=\frac{1}{(a_1-a_2) ... }$ distinct $a_i$
Restatement of Question for Easier Reference
Prove that if $f=\frac{1}{(x-a_1)*(x-a_2)...}$,
for distinct $a_i$  then $f=\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{k_2}{x-a_2}+...$ where $k_1=\frac{1}{a_1-a_2} ... \tag{Eq. 1}$
Motivation: Steps to Solve $k_1$ and $k_2$ if $f=\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{k_2}{x-a_2}+...$ Exists
If $f=\frac{1}{(x-a_1)*(x-a_2)...}=\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{k_2}{x-a_2}+...$, distinct $a_i$ , then start as follows:
Multiply left and right sides by $x-a_1$ yielding:
$$f=\frac{x-a_1}{(x-a_1)*(x-a_2)...}=\frac{k_1*(x-a_1)}{x-a_1}
+\frac{k_2*(x-a_1)}{x-a_2}+... \tag{Eq. 2}$$
Then take the limit $\underset{x \to {a_1}} \lim  f$:
$$\underset{x \to {a_1}} \lim  f=
\frac{1}{(a_1-a_2)...}=\underset{x \to {a_1}} \lim \frac{k_1*(x-a_1)}{x-a_1}
+\frac{k_2*(x-a_1)}{x-a_2}+... =k_1$$
$$\tag{Eq. 3}$$
Then, from Equation 3, arrive at Equation 4:
$$\underset{x \to {a_1}} \lim  k_1 = \frac{1}{(a_1-a_2)...} \tag{Eq. 4}$$
But how is it possible to show that the Equality Represented by Equation 1 always exists given $f=\frac{1}{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...}$, distinct $a_i$ ?
I found this one Swarthmore University Reference on "Partial Fraction Expansion (or Decomposition)", but I still do not understand the proof of the concept.
Also, I found the Wolfram Partial-Fraction-Calculator, but I still do not understand how it goes from the multiplied roots in the donominator to the individual roots $\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}...$, the circumstances where this calculation is a proven identity, and the circumstances not provable.
Also I find the Wikipedia reference not so easy for me to understand.
Is there a contained, clear, and concise proof of the equality?
I think that I am understanding the concept of a Polynomial GCD from this reference at Wolfram "PolynomialGCD".
For instance, if one wants to compute the Polynomal GCD of the following polynomials:
$$\text{PolynomialGCD( }(x+3)^2*(x-2)*x,(x-2)*(x+3)*(x-1) 
\text{ ) }\\=(x-2)*(x+3)$$ $$\tag{Eq. 5}$$
I am starting to understand the concepts of the "Fundamental Theorem of Algebra" from "Further linear algebra. Chapter II. Polynomials." by Andrei Yafaev.  This ties together the concepts of prime numbers and an irreducible polynomials.
Maybe one way to start towards the answer is to take a simple case.
Say $$f=\frac{k_1}{x-a_1}+\frac{k_2}{x-a_2} \tag{Eq. 6}$$
where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are distinct.
So multiply both sides by $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)$ yielding:
$$f*(x-a_1)(x-a_2)=(k_1)*(x-a_2)+(k_2)*(x-a_1) \tag{Eq. 7}$$
So, to get rid of the $x$ contribution in the numerator, set $k_1=-k_2$. Also, the numerator needs to be $1$; so in this case $-k_1*a_2-k_2*a_1=1$ so $k_1*a_1-k_1*a_2=1$ so then $k_1=\frac{1}{a_1-a_2}$ and $k_2=\frac{1}{a_2-a_1}$.
Dividing Equation 7 again by $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)$ yields (as was to be proven for two variables $a_1$ and $a_2$):
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)}$$
So I am looking for an answer similar to this one that extends the concept using simple math.  Already the math listed here is very helpful for a separate question that I am in the process of answering, namely:
"Help with the indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{2x^4 + 3x^2 + 5}$"
Thank you for your comments and help that assisted me with the thought process to get the result for two distinct variables without advanced math concepts.
If someone could also write-up a self-contained similar answer, I would greatly appreciate that!

That is the simplest case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition : $f(x) = 1/q(z)$ where $q$ is a polynomial with pairwise distinct roots.

All of this is wrong, if the $a_i$ are not distinct.

@GerryMyerson:  I updated the question to specifically address unique $a_i$;  thank you for your input.

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4362060/42969

Here is a proof by induction. Given $n\in \Bbb Z_+$ and distinct constants $a_1,...,a_n\,$, we need to prove that $$\prod_{j=1}^n\frac1{x-a_j}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$$
for some constants $c_1,...,c_n$.
First, note that the result is immediate for $n=1$ (with $c_1=1$). Now suppose the result to have been established for $n=k\,$:
$$\prod_{j=1}^k\frac1{x-a_j}=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$$
for some $c_1,...,c_k\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$\begin{align}\prod_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac1{x-a_j}&=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{(x-a_j)(x-a_{k+1})}\\&=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{a_j-a_{k+1}}\left(\frac1{x-a_j}-\frac1{x-a_{k+1}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j/(a_j-a_{k+1})}{x-a_j}+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^kc_j/(a_{k+1}-a_j)}{x-a_{k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{c'_j}{x-a_j},\end{align}$$
where $c'_j:=c_j/(a_j-a_{k+1})\;(j=1,...,k)$ and $c'_{k+1}:=\sum_{j=1}^kc_j/(a_{k+1}-a_j).$
So the result holds also for $n=k+1$. By induction, the result holds for all $n=1,2,...$.

Thank you John Bentin for a nice answer!  I would appreciate if you could add an example section for two variables to make the answer a little more concrete.  Thank you for your help.  I am still digesting what you wrote before giving your answer the check mark excluding additional answer submissions.

@StephenElliott : I have slightly simplified the introduction and corrected a typo. The proof depends on $k$ being allowed to take any value ($1,2,3,...$); that's the idea of induction. So writing it out for, say, $k=2$ and deducing the result for $k=3$ rather misses the point. If there is a particular step that isn't clear, please point it out, and I will try to explain it further.

Hello @John Bentin:  I tried to understand the proof for two concrete cases, n=1 and n=2 and tried also to provide more guidance for those needing simple steps to understand the proof.  I edited your original proof.  Please update the edited version for the concrete case n=2 from n=1 so that I might give your answer the check mark.  As you probably can see from my edit, the n=2 step is still escaping me from the proof you wrote.  Please feel free to re-edit as necessary my update to improve it.  Thank you so much for your work so far.

@StephenElliott : Your edit was rejected, before I saw it, by a high-rep user—and I must agree with him. I think that you need to learn the basics on how a proof by induction works; it's not complicated. There are many resources for this.

I was finally able to follow your math for your inductive proof, so I gave your answer a check mark.  I still needed the result specifically for the case $n=2$ because that result is needed for other more simple applications than the general case, one of which I currently am trying to address.  I posted my answer with some additional steps so that I can come back to it and still remember step-by-step how you got to your result, and that I can refer to it for those without advanced math background.  Thank you for your excellent work!  I gave your answer the check mark!

Restatement of Question for Clarity and Mathematical Inductive Approach Towards Its Solution
This answer attempts to follow John Bentin's proof that is well-suited for an advanced audience, but may no be so easy to grasp for those less-versed in induction and the specifics of it as it applies to the question.
Here is a proof by induction. Given $n\in \Bbb Z_+$ and distinct constants $a_1,...,a_n\,$, we need to prove that $$\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j} \tag{Eq. 1}$$
for some constants $c_1,...,c_n$.
1. Proof by Induction that $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$ for All Distinct $a_j$
First, note that the result is immediate for $n=1$ (with $c_1=1$). Now suppose the result is to be established for $n=k\,$:
$$\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^k(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{x-a_j} \tag{Eq. 2}$$
for some $c_1,...,c_k\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$\begin{align}\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{k+1}(x-a_j)}&=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{(x-a_j)(x-a_{k+1})}
\tag{Eq. 3a}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{a_j-a_{k+1}}\left(\frac1{x-a_j}-\frac1{x-a_{k+1}}\right)
\tag{Eq. 3b}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j/(a_j-a_{k+1})}{x-a_j}+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^kc_j/(a_{k+1}-a_j)}{x-a_{k+1}}
\tag{Eq. 3c}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{c'_j}{x-a_j}, 
\tag{Eq. 3d} \end{align}$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 3}$$
where $c'_j:=c_j/(a_j-a_{k+1})\;(j=1,...,k)$ and $c'_{k+1}:=\sum_{j=1}^kc_j/(a_{k+1}-a_j).$
So the result holds also for $n=k+1$. By induction, the result holds for all $n=1,2,...$.
2. Some Simple Examples that $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$ for All Distinct $a_j$ Starting With $n=1$
From Equation 1, for $n=1$, $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}$=
$\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n=1}(x-a_j)}$=$\frac1{x-a_1}$.
Also, $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j} =\sum_{j=1}^{n=1}\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}
=\frac{c_1}{x-a_1}$.
Obviously, in this case, if $c_1=1$ then
$\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n=1}(x-a_j)}$=$\frac1{x-a_1}=
\sum_{j=1}^{n=1}\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$=$\frac1{x-a_2}$.
This result is as to be proven for the case $n=1$.
3. Induction Example for $k=1$, $n=2$ that $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$ for All Distinct $a_j$
Now the step of induction needs to be taken for the case that $n=2$, since the case of $n=1$ has already been shown true (for unique $a_1$).  The proof by induction proceeds using Equation 2 and Equations 3 (namely Equation 3a, Equation 3b, Equation 3c, and Equation 3d).
4. Proof by Induction that $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n=2}(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n=2}\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$ for All Distinct $a_j$ for the Inductive Case $n=2$
First, note that the result is immediate for $n=1$, $k=1$, and (with $c_1=1$), as was shown in Section 2, "Some Simple Examples that $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$ for All Distinct $a_j$ Starting With $n=1$". Now suppose the result is to be inductively established for $n=2\,$. $k=1\,$ and $k+1=2\,$:
$$\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n=1}(x-a_j)}=
\frac1{x-a_1} =\\= \sum_{j=1}^{n=1}\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}=\frac{c_1}{x-a_1} \tag{From Eq. 2}$$
for some $c_1 \in \Bbb R$, namely here $c_1=1$. Then:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Eq. 3a} \underset{implies}\implies 
\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n=1+1}(x-a_j)}
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n=1}\frac{c_j}{(x-a_j)(x-a_{k+1})} \\
\underset{implies}\implies
\frac1{(x-a_1)}\frac1{(x-a_2)}
&=\frac{c_1}{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)}
\\
\text{Eq. 3b} \underset{implies}\implies
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n=1}
 \frac{c_j}{a_j-a_{k+1}}\left(\frac1{x-a_j}-\frac1{x-a_{k+1}}\right)\\
&=
 \frac{c_1}{a_1-a_{2}}
 \left(\frac1{x-a_1}-\frac1{x-a_{2}}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
$$
\text{Since } \frac1{x-a_1}\frac1{x-a_2}
=\frac1{a_1-a_2}\left(\frac1{x-a_1}-\frac1{x-a_2}\right)
\\
\text{Because }\frac1{a_1-a_2}\left(\frac1{x-a_1}-\frac1{x-a_2}\right)*\left(x-a_1\right)*\left(x-a_2\right)= \\
=\frac1{a_1-a_2}\left(x-a_2-x+a_1\right)=1
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Eq. 3c} \underset{implies}\implies 
\frac1{x-a_1}\frac1{x-a_2}
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n=2}
   \frac{c_j/(a_j-a_{k+1})}{x-a_j}
   +\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n=2} c_j/(a_{k+1}-a_j)}{x-a_{k+1}}\\
\text{Eq. 3d} \underset{implies}\implies
\frac1{x-a_1}\frac1{x-a_2}&=\sum_{j=1}^{n=2}\frac{c'_j}{x-a_j}, 
\\&=\frac1{a_1-a_2}\left(\frac1{x-a_1}-\frac1{x-a_2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
$$\tag{Implied by Eqs. 3}$$
where $c'_j:=c_j/(a_j-a_{k+1=2})\;(j=1)$ and $c'_{k+1}:=\sum_{j=1}^{n=2} c_j/(a_{k+1}-a_j).$
So the result holds also for $n=2$. By induction, from Section 1, "1. Proof by Induction that $\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^n(x-a_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{x-a_j}$ for All Distinct $a_j$" this result also holds for all $n=1,2,...$.
Here, in this section, this result is as to be proven for the case n=2.
